# Why is "The Devil's Backbone" called that?

Tags: title, the-devils-backbone

I have recently seen ***The Devil's Backbone*** by **Guillermo Del Toro.** I didn't quite understand why he chose the name of this film to be *The Devil's Backbone*. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0256009/trivia):

> The film's title refers to the medical condition of spina bifida.

[Specifically](https://whitmanwire.com/arts/2010/11/11/del-toros-the-devils-backbone-horror-with-heart/):

> **The doctor of the orphanage keeps a collection of jars with preserved infants dead from spina bifida**: hence the “Devil’s Backbone” of the title. Each jar is full of a special rum, called “limbo water,” which preserves the baby inside. It’s also rumored to have healing property: and the superstitious villagers buy it by the bottle, which in turn supports the orphanage.